# R: qqplot using cauchy

Tags: r, distribution

I have asked this question [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248623/r-qqplot-problem-using-cauchy?noredirect=1#comment472981_248623)

I want to verify if my data follows a normal or any other type of distribution (like cauchy for example).

I really want to understand how to use `qqplot` =]

Even though the `qqnorm` works well:

```
qqnorm(data);qqline(data)
```

When I try the `qqplot`:

```
qqplot(data, "normal")
qqplot(data, "cauchy")
```

it generates an error:

> Error in plot.window(...) : valores finitos são necessários para 'ylim'

In addition it creates the warning messages:

> 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>   2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Please remember to `dput()` your sample data. Also cross-posting is actually not allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross-posted at CrossValidated

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. This is a programming question with a well-defined answer, and the CV folks kind of implicitly sent the asker here by indicating that programming questions were off-topic for CV. Whether the answer to the programming question will help with the underlying statistical analysis is another matter.

Comment: If anything, it's the CV question that should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the documentation for `qqplot`. The second argument to `qqplot` should be another data vector, not a string. If you want to compare your data to a specific distribution, you can follow the technique used in `qqnorm` and generate a vector of quantiles for any distribution. Let's say x is the data we want to plot:

```
x <- rcauchy(5000)
```

Since x has 5000 elements, we want to generate 5000 evenly-spaced quantiles from our target distribution. First, let's try the normal distribution:

```
y.norm <- qnorm(ppoints(length(x)))
qqplot(x, y.norm)
```

Now let's try the same thing with the Cauchy distribution.

```
y.cauchy <- qcauchy(ppoints(length(x)))
qqplot(x, y.cauchy)
```

(Note that the Cauchy distribution in particular will not behave very well in QQ plots, so this may not actually help you with your real goal.)